# How to create a small ListView by clicking on each items of a main ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView in my app. and when user clicks on each item of it, I want a small ListView with 3 items appear to the user.Could any one suggests me How can I implement this small list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to always show the same items, you could use a popup activity (a custom dialog) when the user clicks on the list. 
The layout of this popup activity will only have a listview, populated in the onCreate() method.

If you want to use ListPopupWindow you can see this example:
[Example on ListPopupWindow](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2078060&seqNum=4)

To open another activity when an item is selected add something like this in the onItemClick method in ListPopupWindowAppActivity class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidFirstActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Keep in mind that ListPopupActivity is available since Api 11, so if you want to target earlier apis you can either use my first option (custom dialog) or the android.widget.PopupWindow. There are several examples for android.widget.PopupWindow, one can be found here:

[Example of PopupWindow](http://android-er.blogspot.gr/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake, I mean do you think ListPopupWindow performs my need?Ho about PopupMenu?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I want to know that Is it possible for a ListPopUpWindow that when a user clicks on each item of it then a new activity starts?

Comment: If not could you please suggest me if there is any custom ListView Pop Up for my need, I mean by clicking on each item of it a new activity could start?

Comment: thanks so much for your answer, but if I want to open some classes which extends from some thing instead of activity for example, to new an object of a class which extends from Dialog, How can I new it's object?

Comment: thanks for your solution,  now I want if the user clicks on an item of the ListPopUpWindow, How can I new an object of a class which extends from Dialog, or some other things which does not extends from Activity?